# WCF service only works on my computer, but my friends get exception tring to use it

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created "LoginRegisterService" and it works perfectly fine on my pc, but when my friend tries to use it using RadminVPN nothing works. He gets the "AuthenticationException"
and something about problems with SSPI. I think that it's something about my app.config files.

Server app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ILoginRegisterService">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings> 
                
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="mexBeh">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <services>
            <service name="BlazeRPServer.LoginRegisterService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBeh">
                <endpoint address="net.tcp://*.*.*.*:8968" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="BlazeRPServer.ILoginRegisterService"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://*.*.*.*:8967" />
                        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://*.*.*.*:8968" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="UserDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\source\repos\BlazeRPClientLauncher\BlazeRPServer\UsersDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Client App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ILoginRegisterService">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://*.*.*.*:8968/" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ILoginRegisterService"
                contract="LoginRegisterService.ILoginRegisterService" name="NetTcpBinding_ILoginRegisterService">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the following reasons:
the certificate has expired or is invalid,
there is a problem with authentication,
to debug Windows authentication errors, you can refer to the following articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/debugging-windows-authentication-errors